# RegEx pattern not quite there

Tags: regex, excel, vba

New to RegEx

I have for row 1 cells like:

```
This That Other [Stuff I want to Keep]
```

I want

```
Suff I want to Keep
```

The pattern gives

```
[Stuff I want to Keep]
```

I cant figure out how to be rid of the brackets i.e `[` and `]`

I can do this with vba but tring something new

Thanks

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim R As Range, Rng As Range
Dim i As Long, LC As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RegistrationData_Prepped")
    LC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set Rng = ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, LC)

        With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
          .Pattern = "\[([^\]]+)\]"

        For Each R In Rng
                If .Test(R.Value) Then
                    R(, 3) = .Execute(R)(0)
                End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Execute(R)(0)` is the entire match, to find the sub-matches you need to call the `.SubMatches` property, ie. `.Execute(R)(0).SubMatches(0)`

Comment: Updated after I got curious and went and looked at the MSDN docs.